# How to add dynamic keys to type for reference in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a scenario where the keys come from backend and I need to create an interface as per the keys. So the dynamic interface will help me bind those properties.

```
const KEYS_FROM_API = ['ARE_YOU_SURE', 'NOT_NOW', 'GO_BACK'];

// added type statically. 
type DYNAMIC_KEYS_TYPE = 'ARE_YOU_SURE' | 'NOT_NOW' | 'GO_BACK'

// created dynamic interface using Record
type ResultType = Record<DYNAMIC_KEYS_TYPE, string>

// RESULT holds key value pair of type object and type of dynamic interface i.e ResultType
const RESULT: ResultType = { ARE_YOU_SURE: 'Are You sure', NOT_NOW: 'Not Now', GO_BACK: 'go back'}

// this works fine
console.log(RESULT.ARE_YOU_SURE, RESULT.NOT_NOW, RESULT.GO_BACK);
```

Here the above code works as per my expectation and also there is no linting error as the RESULT constant has a type where it gets all the properties from the interface.

Now I want to create DYNAMIC_KEYS_TYPE dynamically using the KEYS_FROM_API array. The type must be created dynamically using the Array. In the above  example I have created hard coded.

Help me out creating DYNAMIC_KEYS_TYPE from KEYS_FROM_API array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `as const` to `KEYS_FROM_API` to make it more strict that just `string[]`, then you can use `typeof KEYS_FROM_API[number];`

```
const KEYS_FROM_API = ['ARE_YOU_SURE', 'NOT_NOW', 'GO_BACK'] as const;

// expected: type DYNAMIC_KEYS_TYPE = 'ARE_YOU_SURE' | 'NOT_NOW' | 'GO_BACK'
type DYNAMIC_KEYS_TYPE = typeof KEYS_FROM_API[number];
//   ^? type DYNAMIC_KEYS_TYPE = 'ARE_YOU_SURE' | 'NOT_NOW' | 'GO_BACK'
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA0gUQJoGUD6AxASgeQLJoCCACgJIwC8MA2gOSFYJpI4CqaKrjtANDLQDkcAFTRCA6r34BxHGgBChAMJxaAXRgBDCDFCQoAbgBQRgPSmYAUwAeAB0vAolgCYAuGFACe9mABEkAoR4pEpoiKhowkjECJT8DEws7JzcMAA+-EKiErTpMnKKKrRGXj7+gcGh4ehRMXGlliAAZvDI6Nj4RGTUYACuALYARpYATmrGMDDmMAB6APwm08AjlppOzjDOnmCa-QCWwDB7YE4jTZrAljC9EMcA5jBYDiAjziXeV08QvQA2UMIfOJPUCvAA85SCITCbUi0QQfGgI3uAD5jGYLIxOAAZYQwAAWIB+zh0AGtLJ4YAA3TQ-XpXWyaPYjGDNDyAkCDABWDlgmjAGwaLJaWx2+0Ox1O50uRwAdJ9LN8-gD7EY9NBHghscJ3F9fv9AVQAN4wBLMNgcLgIdz0FYwJAgXowb4rKRZMQ4cTWgQgWDegDuUlkCmUcGtdxAMEGFxJtAAvosLFA8XsdH6XiSdE1jpZVeAIITLDKfiA7gAKTGsHEy01JC2MPgVqtuiQNzWV4QyoOFOAASgMQA)